# How to differentiate the content type in NSData object?

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSData object and I want to differentiate that it has JSON string in it or UIImage or a zip file?

Comment: Easiest is to just distinguish it before you store it in the NSData. Where are you getting the NSData from?

Comment: NSData object is sent to the method and this has to find out which type to content this object has. but the problem is how to find out without any extra information.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you have to check often in your code you can go ahead and make your own NSData implementation.

```
static NSString *const MyJSONDataType = @"JSONDataType";
static NSString *const MyUIImageDataType = @"MyUIImageDataType";
// and so on...

@interface MyData : NSData
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* contentType;
@end

@implementation MyData
@synthesize contentType;
@end
```

Also you can add proper initialization method to specify contentType on the fly.

Comment: Makes more sense to add a category than subclass. Isn't `NSData` a class cluster? Always tricky subclassing.